# jQuery - How to change an object for Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, object, safari

I have a snippet that that takes a div, that is currently hidden, it adds a class and then when a user clicks on a button adds the HTML of the object to the DOM.

It works in FF and IE, but not in Chrome and Safari, in these last 2 it adds the object to the DOM but it doesnt display, like I said it's hidden at the start but the class I add makes it visible. Even more I specifically add css('display', 'block'), which in FF adds a "style=display:block" to the div but not in Safari and Chrome.

Here's the code where I get the HTML of the div I want to add later, I will add a copy for each click:

```
var tempTicket = $('.tickets.extra:hidden').clone();
tempTicket.addClass('linea');
var ticketNombre = $('<div>').append(tempTicket.show().clone()).remove();
```

Here's the code when the user clicks:

```
    $('#addTicket').click(function(){
    //Miro si los tickets anteriores están completos
    console.log("quieres un ticket nuevo");
    if(checkTickets()){
                    ticketNombre.css('display','block'); 
        $(this).before(ticketNombre.html());
            }
     });
```

Any help? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. What are those extra `.clone()` and `.remove()` calls doing there?
2. Calling `.show()` on an element that isn't yet in the DOM is unlikely to work
3. serialising your temporary ticket with `.html()` could lose attributes or properties.

Try this:

```
var ticketNombre = $('.tickets.extra:hidden').clone().addClass('linea');

$('#addTicket').click(function() {
    console.log("quieres un ticket nuevo");
    if (checkTickets()) {
        ticketNombre.insertBefore(this).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: That extra clone and remove is to have one div, and not a div inside a div, that's what happens with your solution.
Thanks for the answer though, where you think is the problem with this? why is it not showing?
Do you need more info?

Comment: @DavidShaikh yes, it would be handy to see your existing mark up. Calling `.remove()` on an element that you only just added would remove everything, including the newly appended ticket.

Comment: @DavidShaikh and please try this changed version, which doesn't create an extra div.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tempTicket = $('.tickets.extra:hidden');


$('#addTicket').click(function() {
    var ticketNombre = $('<div/>').append(tempTicket.clone(true).addClass('linea').show());
    console.log("quieres un ticket nuevo");
    if (checkTickets()) {
        ticketNombre.insertBefore(this);
    }
});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oyotes/7/edit#source)

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by styles.

Since the div was inserted correctly i added

```
display:block!important
```

to the class so it actually showed it.